# Sort by "not on hold" request

Tags: feature-request

Some days nearly the entire front page is questions "on hold":

[image]

I suggest/request some mechanism to filter these out of the display. Perhaps a "not on hold" like "newest" and "featured" and the rest.

Comment: [this search](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3a0%20is%3aquestion) might be helpful while your request is considered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change requests like these would have to be accepted by the dev team, and once accepted, prioritized, and once prioritized, delivered.

The first step is [by no means guaranteed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-request/info), the second step has to compete with [an existing list of high-priority features](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301449/2017-teamdag-project-updates), and the last step alone [takes 6-8 time units](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/273503).

In other words, don't hold your breath.  In the meantime, as as  [@Matt E. Эллен said in the comments](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/sort-by-not-on-hold-request#comment46019_10984), you can use [the `closed:0` (or `closed:false` etc) operator](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3A0%20is%3Aquestion) in the search bar on the main site to get a list of non-closed questions. If you combine this [with other sorts and filters](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/searching), you can get a front page which precisely like the current one, sans closed questions.